# Using Range with presigned url AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I create a presigned url - it generates a `X-Amz-Signature`.

Using this signature in the query param along with the `Range` [query param](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#AmazonS3-GetObject-request-header-Range) causes the signatur to then be invalid. Is there anyway to get around this?

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

Comment: The docs you reference are talking about HTTP headers, _not_ "query param".  How, exactly, are you using the URL and specifying the range you want returned?